# Minus function in Optic Query

Tags: xquery, marklogic, marklogic-optic-api

I have requirement to do minus in one of the use case but in MarkLogic I am not able to use minus function. Is there any alternate way to do this?

```
select table1.value1 from table1 where table1.date = '2020-11-27'
minus
select table1.value1 from table1 where table1.date = '2020-11-26'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The "`MINUS`" operator is a SPARQL operator. Similar functionality is supported in MarkLogic's Optic API using the `op:except()` operator. You can also use the "`MINUS`" operator in SPARQL and `op:from-sparql()` in the Optic API, and the "`EXCEPT`" operator in SQL and `op:from-sql()` in the Optic API.

Answer (score -1):

The minus/subtraction operator in XQuery is "-", like in most languages. The rest of your code looks a bit like SQL to me (though I last used SQL about 30 years ago) and it will all need changing.

I don't now what "Optic Query" is, I'm afraid.

Comment: There is an option to use sql in marklogic but many SQL functions are not supported in MarkLogic

Comment: MarkLogic has an XQuery function library for relational style querying called Optic API.

Comment: Perhaps it was a mistake to tag the question XQuery.